# How to upload .txt file to local node.js server and read back the file contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Basically, I am creating a small game where I save a list of how many times the user has won to a text file and I then want to upload the contents of that text file to my server and would also like the ability to read the contents from my server. Just wondering what's the best way to do this?

My Server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var PORT = 8080;

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('connection successful');
    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if(filePath == './'){
        filePath = './index.html';
    }
    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch(extname){
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
    case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
    }
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if(error){
            response.writeHead(500);
            response.end();
        } else{
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Client code function:

```
var scoresFile;
function xPlayerWinsF(){
    xPlayerWins++;
    scoresFile = new File('scoresfile.txt');
    scoresFile.wrtiteln("X player wins: "+xPlayerWins);
}
```

Thanks in advance.